# Selectively duplicate windows on second monitor

Tags: windows-8, display, debian, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

I'm preparing for a live coding session where I will be giving a talk and programming in front of the audience. I would like the projector to only show my IDE (Visual Studio, emacs, ...), and my computer's screen to display that IDE window + a few notes that I've prepared.

That would be a bit like PowerPoint's presenter mode, only not for PowerPoint: one app appears on both monitors, and others stay on one monitor only.

Could you suggest ways to achieve this? I can use Windows 8 or Linux for my presentation.

Answer (score 2):

What I do in similar situations is use two Emacs frames on the two screens sharing the same buffer. That way you edit on your screen and the text appears on the projection. Other windows (or other emacs-windows in your frame) on your screen do not appear in the projection.

Takes a little to get used to, but for me is a good workaround.

Comment: Ah, very nice! I wonder if there's a way to get the two Emacs windows to share the same window-point.  If not, it should be easy to make a post-command-hook for that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your presentation went well. Though it's already been more than 2years but I'll still answer thinking that someone else might land up here in future :)

You could easily extend your screen (rather duplicating it) and drag Visual Studio (or any app) on the secondary screen. Just type extend monitor in Google or use the below link if you need to know how to do that:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/move-windows-between-multiple-monitors#1TC=windows-7

PS: I'm also looking for any application that can 'selective project' applications and that's how I landed on this page. But the above could have worked well in your case! If I don't find one, I'll think about creating one by myself.

Comment: I don't think that works. I want the IDE to be duplicated, not extended.

Comment: Oh okay. My apologies, I misunderstood that. I'm also looking for some sort of that arrangements. I'm working on it. If I find something for myself, I'll post it here. Basically  what I(we) need is the selective projection of the application/s on external display. So if we have App A and App B opened on the primary monitor, we want App A to be displayed on both the screens and App B only on the primary screen.